# After the Cryptoperiod timespan, do we need to encrypt all the data again?

Tags: pci-dss

As per PCI-DSS we need to dispose the old keys after the timespan. After the cryptoperiod (lets say one year) time span, do I need to encrypt all (20k card holders) the data once again with the newly generated key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since re-crypt all the data could be a pain in the... There are different approaches to this (which is known as "secrets management"):

- **Low security level**: you just keep a list of your private keys and if you need to get old data you can use the old key.
- **Medium security level**: the same as the low level but before leaving all the information encrypted with the old key, each time you access to the secret you re-crypt it with the valid key and you wipe-out your old secret.
- **High security/sensitive data**: yes, you have to re-crypt all your secrets. (Might be extremely costly).

As I usually recommend, don't try to overkill and don't choose "re-crypt" by default, consider asking yourself the following questions:

1. Are your data sensitive in a way that put your business in risk if disclosed?
2. Is the amount of time to re-crypt your data reasonable? (Meanwhile re-enciphering your data you might not have availability of it).
3. Does the information expire with the cryptoperiod as well?
4. Are your keys protected well enough?
5. Is the cryptoperiod/key strength balanced?

[Edit (improving answer as suggested by @LucasKauffman ]

My response has to do with the [PCI-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3.pdf) (sections 3.5-3.6) and you have to read them carefully to be sure you fully understand how to put in practice these methods. I will not paste them here since it is copyrighted material (it is freely available in their webpage).

The PCI-DSS does not contain the exactly points I have made, but it is implied in the document if you read it carefully. Pay special attention to the "guidance" column.

(Feel free to add any grammar/syntax correction since English is not my mother tongue).

Comment: Thank you so much. After reading your answer I got a clear focus on it. Medium level security is best way but have to check the amount of time to re-cryp for sensible data like PAN number. As per your 5th point we have a plan to secure the crypto keys in HSM device i.e Thales.Do you have any idea on this or is there any other best HSM device  available?

Comment: @professorTuring, since  this is in reference to PCI-DSS compliance, can you also provide the sections where this is detailed? Note that while your answer might be right in sense of storing sensitive encrypted data, PCI-DSS has very strict rules on how this data should be managed.

Comment: @Lucas Cryptoperiod is in 3.6.4 section. and I have a doubt in 3.5.2 section to store the secure crypto device which HSM we have to use to protect/stored the key Thales or something else? do you have any idea?

Comment: @LucasKauffman I have added the reference as you suggested.

Comment: @chandru any HSM that fits your needs will do the trick. I believe stackexchange is against service/providers recommendations.